# Indexing a value based on name in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am new to R shiny. I have created a variable which has the output of regression.Here is my sample code.

```
 reg <- reactive({
        a=lm(y~x1+x2+x3)
         result_list <- list()
         result_list[[1]] =a$coefficients
        })

        summary<-reactive({
        reg()
        reg[[1]]["x1","Estimate"] 

        })
```

but I am unable to get the estimate for "x1" using the above code. Also, I cannot use the $ operator in shiny for

```
reg$coefficients["x1","Estimate"]
```

Please help me to get the estimate for the variable in shiny. I understand this is a single line code in R, but I am unable to replicate it in shiny.

Comment: Reactive results should be called as a function call `reg()` so ideally it has to be `reg()$coeffecients.....`

Comment: And you also have to return a value inside `reg` reactive function instead of assigning the result to result_list[[1]] or result_lsit

Comment: @amrrs Thanks. Helped a lot.